# applying conditions to arrays with different channels

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following simple program

```
import numpy as np

thepixels = np.array([[0, 5 ], [5, 0 ]])
print(thepixels.shape)
cnd= thepixels[:]>3
print(cnd)
print(thepixels[cnd])

layer4= np.zeros((2,2,4),dtype=np.uint8)
print("the array")
print(layer4)
print("the info")
print(layer4.dtype)
print(layer4.shape)
```

Which gives the output

```
(2, 2)
[[False  True]
 [ True False]]
[5 5]
the array
[[[0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]]]
the info
uint8
(2, 2, 4)
```

you can see that there is an array of shape (2,2) which serves me to find a condition that I want to apply to my zero array of shape (2,2,4)

What I am scratching my head to do (with numpy) is:

Given:

- a channel number:  nchannel
- a value:  value

apply the condition so that I can have the `value` in the array on the `nchannel.

For example:

nchannel= 1
value=10

What I want to get is

```
[[[0 0 0 0]
  [0 10 0 0]]

 [[0 10 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]]]
```

or if value is 50 and nchannel is 4 then

```
[[[0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 50]]

 [[0 0 0 50]
  [0 0 0 0]]]
```

How can I apply the condition to get these arrays?

P.S. I know that by doing `layer4[:,:,nchannel]=value` I can apply the value unconditionally to the channel, but how do I apply it depending on the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not crystal clear to me, but at least this gives me your expected results.

```
...
layer4[cnd, nchannel] = new_value
...
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I am having problems understanding numpy's way of addressing condition and channels. Can you explain how did you come with this solution?